# Will Google crawl this URL?

Tags: jquery, seo

I'm using the [jquery address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) module for a good portion of my site. The problem I'm running into is that I created two seperate URL formats, one for offline (guest users) and one for online (logged in users). For example my two formats look like this:

online:
http://my-site.com/#view_profile=5

offline:
http://my-site.com/view_profile=5

Will Google crawl the **online** URL format or do I need to add a "#!' for the [pretty URL](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html) format in order for Google to crawl it? If this is the case is it a matter of just pre-pending an '!' mark to the hash mark?

I really like the jquery address module because it allows greater flexibility in my design but I'm afraid it's effecting any SEO efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need to adapt "#!" scheme inw your URLs, since Google does consider them AJAX crawlable.

**First case**

```
http://my-site.com/#view_profile=5
```

This URL won't be crawled by Google, `http://my-site.com/` will be crawled instead, since `'#view_profile=5'` portion of URL is not sent to the server (there is no way to do that).
But if you adapt `'#!'` scheme, you tell Google to send aditional portion after `'#'` to the server, in special `$_REQUEST['_escaped_fragment_']` parameter.

**Second case**
What gets generated here is crawled by GoogleBot...

More to read here [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](http://code.google.com/intl/sk/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html) or feel free to ask.

Comment: Updated link: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started